# Perfoming perfomance testing on frontend for Angular web application

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing

I am in need of performing frontend load test for AngularJS application. Is there any way to perform it?

Also, note it cannot be done in JMeter.

Comment: What do you mean by FrontEnd load testing ? the fronend is a single user talking to a single server, or do you want to use the front end to load a server using multiple browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

LoadNinja is a frontend performance testing tool (i.e. not at the protocol level).

It is expensive but there are not many performance testing tools around that operate against the UI.

https://loadninja.com/

Answer (score 0):

LoadRunner has got TruClient for that and NeoLoad has RealBrowser. SilkPerformer has also got something simular.

Those protocols is Loadtesttools are not intended for (very) high loads, because they take a lot more resources than tests at http(s) protocol level.